# Post data and refresh page

Tags: php, html, http-post

I have an edit-form page to edit my website posts.
It uses post method to the same page.
If the form is compiled correctly shows up a congrats message.

**The problem:**

When users hit the refresh button the script  tries to repost the data again to page.
Is there a way to avoid this?

thanks

Luca

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The general outline of the PRG pattern is this:

```
if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' )
{
     /// do your magic

     $_SESSION['error'] = "Thanks for your message!";

     // this should be the full URL per spec, but "/yourscript.php" will work
     $myurl = ...;

     header("Location: $myurl");
     header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
     die("redirecting");
}

if ( isset($_SESSION['error']) )
{
     print "The result of your submission: ".$_SESSION['error'];
     unset($_SESSION['error']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [PRG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the PRG pattern already mentioned above! 
Just for completeness I add the possibility of using javascript history.replaceState if your forms depend on js (e.g. noscript should invalidate the form or something similar...).

```
<script>
  window.history.replaceState({}, '#no-reload');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called the [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. You do this by responding to a POST request with a 302/303 Redirect, which prevents that troublesome behavior on the client.

You can read more about this in the link I posted above.