# Do not refresh php page

Tags: php, mysql, page-refresh

On my page, after the user has submitted a code, the script makes a new record in the database.  If after he has submitted the code the user hits refresh, it will make a duplicate record in the database. If he hits refresh 10 times, it will make 10 records with the same data...

Is there some way I can make the page not to refresh for the second time?? Or to limit the number of refreshes the page can get? What solutions can be applied to avoid this situation?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you post your code please

Comment: use ajax w/delete form data or use tokens

Comment: Post the data to some other page. After inserting to Database, redirect the flow to original page

Comment: The simplest way is to make a redirect to same page after insert in db in order to get lost post/get parameters.

Comment: @shin unset would only delete the variables from the script not what the browser remembers

Comment: @Class,I understand.I think ,The best way is to redirect to the same page after executing the query.

Answer (score 0):

Before adding the record into the data table, use `select query` to check the data is alreary exists or not in the data table and redirect the page to a new page, say thank you or confirmation of insertion.

```
Select id from TABLE where data='".$_POST["data"]."';
....
....
if(empty($rs["id"])){
// insert the data in table;
}else{
// do edit or skip to redirect
}
```

and Rediret

```
header("location:thankyou.php");
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the PHP script that produces the form is the same one that processes it. You may want to consider setting up a separate PHP script to handle the form. For example:

```
<form action="action_handler.php" method="post">
```

Then, at the end of `action_handler.php`, you would redirect to the original page as follows:

```
header('Location: original_page.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

After the records are saved in the database, use `header()` and redirect to the same page.

Check the answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427428/post-data-and-refresh-page), maybe you can use the same code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple one is `unset($_POST["data"])`  after inserting it to database or try `header('location:.')`

Comment: But this won't prevent the browser from re-submitting the post data.

Answer (score 0):

When dealing with POST-data you should always employ a POST/REDIRECT/GET setup ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get). This way, when a user refreshes the destination page, nothing really happens besides a refresh.

The best way for a redirect method is to use status code 303 ([HTTP Status Codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)), which tells the browser that the POST-data has been received, processed and that the user should go to a new page for the 'response'. When a user hits 'back' he or she should get a message that the page is no longer available or valid (this disabling rePOSTing via that route).

You can use this example to redirect to another page (fairly generic example, but I have baseline code I could use):

```
header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
header("Location: http://www.yourdomain.com/desitnation.php");
```